# React-native trouble : How to pass my refreshNavifation succesfully?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-navigation

Hey guys I am trying to refresh my react-native app onPress of a button in my LoginScreen.js, to do so i call a function defined in the App.js that will impact a useState and cause the app component to refresh (at least in theory)

here take a look at my **LoginScreen.js code**, and yes i call my "handleLogin" function later onPress of a button:

```
const LoginScreen = (route) => {
// const LoginScreen = () => {
  
  const { refreshNavigation } = route.params;

  const [token, setToken] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const navigation = useNavigation();


  const handleLogin = async () => { 
    try {
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
 
     const userToken = await getToken();
     await SecureStore.setItemAsync('jwt', JSON.stringify(userToken));
     setToken(userToken);
    } catch (err) {
     console.log(err.message)
    }

    getValueFor('jwt')
    refreshNavigation();
    
}
```

and here is code that is relevant to my refreshNavigation function in my **App.js** :

```
export default function App() {
  // useState qui permet de refresh le fichier APP.JS
  const [refreshKey, setRefreshKey] = useState(0);

  
  // Expo font hook, s'assure de charger les polices
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Montserrat': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    'Montserrat-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
    'Montserrat-Italic': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Italic.ttf'),
  });

  // déclare les etats de connexion pour le store zustand
  const { connected, setConnected, setDisconnected } = connectionStore();


  function refreshNavigation() {
    setRefreshKey(refreshKey + 1);
  }
  
return (
    <NavigationContainer>

    <Stack.Navigator key={refreshKey}>
      {
        !connected &&
        <>
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown : false}} name="Login" component={LoginScreen} initialParams={{refreshNavigation}}/>
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown : true}} name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown : true}} name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown : false}} name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />

        </>
      }
      {
        connected &&
        <>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        </>
      }

  </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>
```

So here I am trying to understand why my project returns me the following error :

- ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshNavigation' of undefined *

Anyway thanks in advance for any help i could get

I believe that it might have something to do with the fact that i do not technically navigate to m y LoginScreen.js, i just land on it because it's the first of my stack navigator ?